# How to hide jpanelmenu after load page

Tags: jquery, jpanelmenu

Please go to my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/zz5nk/). I want to hide that Jpanel after load the page. How can I do that?

here is the code from [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/zz5nk/).

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
      menu: '#menu',
      trigger: '.menu-trigger',
      duration: 300
   });
   jPM.on();

   $(".menu").click(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr("link");
      alert(url);
      $( "#contents" ).load(url+" #area");
  });
});
```

Comment: Is jpanel hidden initially? Is jpanel means UL LI having id as #menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
   menu: '#menu',
   trigger: '.menu-trigger',
   duration: 300
  });
  jPM.on();

   $(".menu").click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr("link");
   alert(url);
   $( "#contents" ).load(url+" #area");
   jPM.close();//Add this line

   });
 });
```

Comment: I used it before dude. When I used it. jPanel going to totally `OFF`. It's mean, can't go to the left navigation again. :-(

Comment: Is it working now as you want? @YeshanSachithaKPerera